# Rsync, --delete not remove files on target

Tags: backup, rsync

I run a game server with a plugin that puts hourly server backups in /backups. After 1 day the plugin saves 2 backups/day. I want to sync this backup directory to a remote server with files older than 2 days so that it doesn't sync files that eventually will be deleted by the end of the day. To do this I run this script:

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime +2 -exec rsync -vPhd -e "ssh -p 512" --ignore-existing --delete {} me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/ \;
```

However, --delete does not actually delete old files on target host. Is this because of mtime? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec` in your find will rsync every file separately, because `find` will return 1 file at a time. So your `--delete` will not work because your line is basicly an `scp`

What you could do is

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime -2 -printf '%P\n' | rsync -avz --progress --delete --exclude-from=- -e "ssh -p 512" /path/backups/ me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/
```

This will rsync the folder `backups` to `server-backups`, but excludes files younger than 2 days. You can put a `--dry-run` in the rsync to test it first.

Comment: after adding -d it works just as intended, thanks for the help!

Comment: I've tried to use this with rcon but it doesn't seem to work... any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use --recursive

It should look like this:

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime +2 -exec rsync -vPhd -e "ssh -p 512" --ignore-existing --recursive --delete {} me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the same thing happens, no files were deleted on target.